# Programmatically extracting Adobe PDF package files

Tags: pdf, adobe

We have a bunch of documents in our organization that were inadvertently saved as [Adobe PDF packages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WSE034CA46-D08F-4fff-AA3C-FF04510DAEF0.html) (also known as PDF 1.7 "collections").
We would like to convert these to normal PDFs (most of these "packages" contain one bog-standard pdf file), but given the number of files, it's not possible manually.

Any Adobe expert know whether:

1. There is an open-source or free library that handles PDF package format that I can write a script around?
2. Does Adobe Pro 9 have a relevant scriptable interface that would allow me to extract the relevant file from each package?

Alternatively, I'm looking at a macro-based approach, but I'd rather not go this route until investigating other options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bunch of digging around, I found [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/), which is distributed as source and binary on many platforms.

It does almost all of what we need to do, and we can now iterate through our documents and recursively call pdftk on each (some are multi-level attachment chains).

Answer (score 1):

Note pdftk will only burst pages of the visible document into individual documents. The hidden documents remain hidden.

The option you need to use is unpack_files.

Yet another unwanted obfuscation format to hinder interoperability therefore classified as malware.

Answer (score 1):

Using Adobe Acrobat Professional combine all into one pdf and then split by bookmark level

Comment: Programmatically? Not manually?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this thread is few years old but if anyone is looking for free utility to extract files from PDF packages  (especially from large collections) then check the free utility [ByteScout PDF Multitool](http://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html): it was tested against 500+ MB package files to extract hundreds of multilevel chained attachments.

*Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with ByteScout*